# My STL format export is only 1KB in size? Any idea what went wrong?

Tags: modeling

I created a simple model and exported the file as an STL. However, when I go to the folder the file is a Certificate Trust List and is only 1KB in size. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Can you try exporting with another version of Blender?

Comment: that's normal, do you have problem when importing it again ?

Comment: I'm trying to send it to shapeways to have it 3d printed. However I did just try import, stl, the file, on blender and it got imported but there's nothing there. It's an empty object with no mesh

Comment: select the object before exporting

Comment: @Chebhou ok that definitely increased my file size, though it still seems too small at 16,000 KB. I'm gonna try to upload to shapeways now

Comment: try importing it again

Comment: Chebhou yep it worked on import now too. My main thing though is uploading to shapeways which I believe is working. Not sure I think the site is having some difficulties all around cause it's very slow

Answer (score 2):

When exporting to stl format in blender make sure to select your objects, or it will export an empty object instead.

The .stl file on windows system will be recognized as a "Certificate Trust List" so instead of double click to open it , <kbd>RMB</kbd> and choose open with then your software