# Problem exporting blender files to stl for 3d printing

Tags: modeling

When I export a 484K blender file to stl for 3D printing (xyz da vinci junior) it becomes 84 bytes (empty).The files that work are reduced in size by a factor of 50  from 484K to 9.84K whereas this file reduces by a factor of 50 times 100. Any ideas on how to fix it ? Thanks,with your help I've solved it.

Comment: you may need to provide the 3d file in question for us to do some troubleshooting. Use the link here to upload your file http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28171/my-stl-format-export-is-only-1kb-in-size-any-idea-what-went-wrong?rq=1 ?